# CSS a fixed-width image and one taking up the empty space

Tags: css, layout, aspect-ratio

I'm desperately trying to format two images side by side using CSS.
I want the first one to be fixed-size and the second one to take up the remaining width (but it should stop growing when it has the same height as the first one). This is my code:

```
<span style="height:80px; width:100%">
    <img src="images/navicon.png" style="width:60px; height:60px; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; "/>
    <img src="images/logo.png" style="max-height:60px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;" />
</span>
```

But instead of the second image shrinking (maintaining aspect-ratio) when there is not enough space, the line breaks.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks to all of your input I'm almost there: I can restrict the height like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/Low7k16d/8/) but then the width of the second image is too long. Or I can compute the remaining width like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/Low7k16d/10/) but then the height is strangely smaller than it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/60/abstract/1"></div>
    <div class="image image-auto"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/60/abstract/1"></div>
</div>

<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/abstract/1"></div>
    <div class="image image-auto"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/60/abstract/1"></div>
</div>

<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/60/abstract/1"></div>
    <div class="image image-auto"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.image {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 80px; /*Line added to limit height*/
}

.image-auto {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

And I updated the Pen: http://codepen.io/czoka/pen/XbJXVO

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question to be more precise: I don't want the second image to zoom until it's very pixelated and cut it off then. It should rather stop growing when it has reached the height of the first one.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you want your second image to fit in the space left on the right without changing the aspect ratio. Does it matter if it won't fill in the entire space?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for, or the images on the right should not grow over the height of the images en the left?

Comment: I want the image on the left to be a certain fixed size (e.g. 80px height). The one on the right can be as wide as is possible, but not higher than the first one (80px). Aspect-ratio should be preserved and nothing should be cut off. 
 
I don't want to resize the original pictures with a photo editor, because I use them in multiple CSSs with different image sizes. 
 
Your solution unfortunately doesn't restrict the height of the second image.

Comment: Adding a max-height restriction at the right place does the job. [http://jsfiddle.net/Low7k16d/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/Low7k16d/12/). I will accept this solution if I don't find anything with less Flexbox and more browser support ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This possible solution requires CSS **[`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)**, see the demo follows.

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
span:nth-child(2) img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></span>
    <span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></span>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Low7k16d/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question to be more precise: I don't want the second image to zoom until it's very pixelated and cut it off then. It should rather stop growing when it has reached the height of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question but this is what I thought you mean.

**NOTE:** this is my updated version of sdcr's answer.

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 80px;

    font-size: 0;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:10px;
}
span:nth-child(1) img {
    max-height: 60px;

}
span:nth-child(2) img {
    width: 100%;
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></span>
    <span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-924-67-9.jpg" /></span>
</div>
```

See jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Low7k16d/4/

Comment: With `white-space: nowrap;` this can be prevented, but then the line is longer than 100%